# Seamless way to check if user likes page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

So, I am using an iFrame on my tab and I am doing one of those "like roadblocks" where the user needs to like the page in order to view the secret content. Is there a better and more seamless way of doing this then having to ask for permission?

I know for tabs built with FBML, they dont ask for permission, but I am guessing that is because it is NOT an iframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course you can! As mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/), Facebook will send you some extra details in the `signed_request`:

> When a user navigates to the Facebook
>   Page, they will see your Page Tab
>   added in the next available tab
>   position. Broadly, a Page Tab is
>   loaded in exactly the same way as a
>   Canvas Page. When a user selects your
>   Page Tab, you will received the
>   signed_request parameter with one
>   additional parameter, page. This
>   parameter contains a JSON object with
>   an id (the page id of the current
>   page), admin (if the user is a admin
>   of the page), and liked (if the user
>   has liked the page). As with a Canvas
>   Page, you will not receive all the
>   user information accessible to your
>   app in the signed_request until the
>   user authorizes your app.

The code taken from my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) should be something like:

```
<?php
if(empty($_REQUEST["signed_request"])) {
    // no signed request where found which means
    // 1- this page was not accessed through a Facebook page tab
    // 2- a redirection was made, so the request is lost
    echo "signed_request was not found!";
} else {
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);
    if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
        echo "You are not a fan!";
    } else {
        echo "Welcome back fan!";
    }
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
?>
```

**UPDATED CODE:** While the previous code would work. I wasn't *checking* the validity of the request. This means someone could tamper the request and send you false information (*like setting the `admin` to `true`!*). Code has been updated, following the [`signed_request` documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) approach.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out, but I do appreciate you posting the answer in case anyone else needs to know.

Comment: Great answer and tutorial.