# Like to unlock content on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, unlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seamless way to check if user likes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

How can I make a like to unlock content tab on Facebook?

I´ve seen some applications that let me do this, but I don't want any branding on my tab.

Comment: Try it: http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-jquery/2822035?ref=onepress

Answer (score 1):

You need to query page_fan, example using JavaScript SDK:

```
            var fqlQuery = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + pageId + " and uid=" + userId;
            var query = FB.Data.query(fqlQuery);
            query.wait(function (rows) {

                if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == userId) {
                    alert(true);
                } else {
                    alert(false);
                }
            });
```

I think that will you need to ask for this permission: user_likes

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to find if the user is a fan or not. You can use the `signed_request` to do so. "You will need to register a Facebook application". Read more about `signed_requests` 
at *[Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)*.

Then you can use the returned data to find if the user is a fan, administrator, etc.