# How to check if user is a fan of facebook page by Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to check if user is a fan of a specific Facebook page, I have tried searching in Google but I haven't found the answer yet.

I am an admin of fanpage. I am having a promotion program on my page and becoming a fan of my page is a requirement. I want to check if users like my page to give them presents. Because of a large users, I want to create a tool to do it.

Do you have any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permission. That way, you can get his Page likes with the `/me/likes` endpoint.

Be aware that you are not allowed to incentivize Page likes, users must like a Page only because they really want to, you can´t reward them in any way or gate content behind a Page like.

Comment: In this case, I am an admin of fanpage. I am having a promotion program on my page and becoming a fan of my page is a requirements. I want to check if users like my page to give them presents. Because of a large users, I want to create a tool to do it.

Comment: @LavendiOtamedi This is not allowed as luschn wrote

Comment: @Tobi Is there any way to list all members of my page?

Comment: no, there is no way, and again: it´s not allowed to require page likes or reward users. you will never get user_likes approved in the review process for that.

Comment: You don't get what I mean. May be I express my idea badly. I don't need permission to require page like through FB API or reward users on Facebook. I only need checking if users like page. It seems there is no way, according you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `/me/likes/{page_id}` where `{page_id}` is an actual page object id as a shortcut.

If the user doesn't like the page, you'll receive a response like

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```